# What is the best way to parse Bazel build event protocol in search of the target that failed the build and the error message?

Tags: bazel

#### Context

Although Bazel displays the build error message while building locally, understanding which target failed the build graph is not as easy - the default error message will point to the root target and not necessarily the target that contains the error. This is not optimal, as in the case where the build graph is very big and users will have to build many targets that are known to be good until they hit the bad one.

Other than that, acessing this message from CI is not practical, users need to scroll hundreds - if not thousands - of lines (after waiting for them to load) and search for the error message. **I would like to extract the exact target that failed the build graph and get a meaningful description of the error in order to present it to developers, so they can quickly reproduce the error locally and fix their changes.**

#### What do I have so far?

1. Bazel [Build Event Protocol](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-event-protocol.html) offers a rich set of data that should contain the desired information;
2. After setting up Bazel to output the build events into a bin file, I've created a CLI that takes this file and parses it as per the [`build_event_stream.proto`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto) specification;
3. After parsing it, the best I was able to obtains is:
4. events → actions → filter for `javac` → get the failed target via `getLabel()`. This is not ideal since it depends on filtering the results of the `javac`. In a big company, there would be dozens of compilers from different programming languages. **It would be great to have a way to get the target that failed the build in a language agnostic way**;
5. events → progress → filter for `srterr not empty`. Aparently the progress is the equivalent of the messages that Bazel prints to the terminal. Using regular expressions I can try to extract information such as the file where the compilation error has ocurred, the line of it, etc. Despite that there is no link between this error message and the target that failed.

#### Resources

- [Protobuf specification for the build event protocol](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventstream/proto/build_event_stream.proto)
- [How to find the target failed build from build event protocol?](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4568) - someone that had the same question as I did in 2018;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semi-reliable way of finding errors in the build event protocol files could be looking for `ActionCompletedId` events. As per specification:

> Identifier of an event reporting that an action was completed (not all actions are reported, only the ones that can be considered important; this includes all failed actions).

It comes with an `ActionExecuted` message as payload which carries information on how an action has terminated, including its stderr. Although the specification says

> consumers of the build-event protocol must not assume that only failed actions are posted.

I found it reliably enough to check the exit code, which is included in the message.

Comment: Awesome, that works. The path is events --> executed actions --> filter for exit code greater than 0 then the target that failed the build get be acquired via `label` field and the error message can ge read from the file indicated in the `stderr_.file_`